# ERROR : value += is not a member of Long Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to do some aggregates for publishing metrics to Cloud watch. I adding my metrics count logic when before saving the final result. Basically I am trying to get the count of customers with value > 0 for each column. So that I can get number and percentage.

```
case class ItemData(totalRent : Long, totalPurchase: Long, itemTypeCounts: Map[String, Int] ) extends Serializable


import scala.collection.JavaConversions._


class ItemDataMetrics(startDate: String) {

  var totals: ItemData = _

  def countNonZero(c: Long): Int = {if (c > 0) 1 else 0}


  def accumulate(featureData: ItemData) {

    totals.totalRent+= countNonZero( featureData.totalRent )
    totals.totalPurchase += countNonZero( featureData.totalPurchase )

    for (entry <- featureData.itemTypeCounts.entrySet) {

      if (totals.itemTypeCounts.contains( entry.getKey )) {
        totals.itemTypeCounts.updated( entry.getKey, entry.getValue + countNonZero( entry.getValue ) )
      } else {
        totals.itemTypeCounts.put( entry.getKey, countNonZero( entry.getValue ) )
      }
    }
  }
}

 var totalCustomer : Int = 0
 val itemMetrics: ItemDataMetrics = new ItemDataMetrics(startDate)

 val resultValue = resultDF.map( {
      r => {
        val customerId = r.getAs[String]( "customerId" )

        val totalRent = r.getAs[Long]( "totalRent" )
        val totalPurchase = r.getAs[Long]( "totalPurchase" )


        val itemTypeCounts = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "itemType" )


        val items = ItemData( totalRent, totalPurchase, itemTypeCounts)

        totalCustomer = totalCustomer + 1

        itemMetrics.accumulate(items)

        val jsonString = JacksonUtil.toJson( items)

        (customerId, jsonString)
      }
    } )

    publishMetrics(startDate, featureMetrics)   ---- publishes metrics to cloud watch

   resultValue.saveAsTextFile("S3:....")
```

But keep getting error :

```
<console>:26: error: value += is not a member of Long
           totals.totalRent += countNonZero( itemData.totalRent )
                                    ^
<console>:27: error: value += is not a member of Long
           totals.totalPurchase += countNonZero( itemData.totalPurchase )

<console>:36: error: value entrySet is not a member of Map[String,Int]
           for (entry <- itemData.itemTypeCounts.entrySet) {
```

I am new to scala/spark . Can some tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two conditions under which `x += y` is valid in Scala:

1. `x` has a method named `+=`, which will be called with `y` as the argument, or
2. `x` is a `var` and has a method named `+`. In that case `x` will be assigned the result of `x + y`

Now `Long` only has a `+` method, no `+=` method. Therefore you can only use `+=` on a `Long` if it's a `var`. Now you didn't show the definition of the `ItemData` class, but since you got an error, I assume that `totals.totalRent` is a `val` (or a `def`). Thus it can't be reassigned and you can't use `+=` on it.

Comment: Updated with ItemData. Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: @Newbie You can make `totalRent` and `totalPurchases` `var`s, but you might want to change your whole approach to not require mutation at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, `+=` generally takes a mutable variable (`var`), adds a value to it, and reassigns the new value to the variable. This will only work with `var` as this is a mutable variable. It will not work with `val` (immutable) or with a function definition.

In the line below, `totalRent` is a `val` and reassignment cannot take place.

```
totals.totalRent+= countNonZero( featureData.totalRent )
```

You can fix this by using `var` in your case class variable definitions instead of the default `val`. See below:

```
case class ItemData(var totalRent : Long, var totalPurchase: Long, var itemTypeCounts: Map[String, Int] ) extends Serializable
```

This will allow the `+=` reassignment to take place.

Comment: Is there any way around to do this ?

Comment: I have updated the above with a suggested solution. In your ItemData class, you can set the totalRent, totalPurchase  and itemTypeCounts fields as vars.